# An alternative for the javax.ws.rs package which doesn't treat the 429 error code

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I'm using this library in java: Maven: javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1.

But when I try to use the enum "Status" which is inside the "Response" class (at the Core folder)-

I see it doesn't treat a 429 error code.

Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Without pom file, Java code etc. it is impossible to say something useful.

Comment: You don't have to use the enum. You should be able to use any integer you want to set a status code.